# Pulled Pork for a large crowd

Tags: crockpot, bulk-cooking

How much pulled pork will 26 pounds (12 Kg) of raw boneless pork butt make?

I am making this in several crock-pots. This is my first time making pulled pork for a large crowd

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your portion size.  If you figure a 6 oz portion and 45 - 50% loss on boneless pork butt (based on some internet research)...I would estimate that 26 lbs would feed around 35 people.

Comment: I suspect OP wants to know how much will be lost to unusable (or evaporated, or water drained off) portions.

Comment: @derobert fair point.  My answer is being edited.

Answer (score 1):

Each Kg (2.2 lb) is will result in at least 0.6 Kg (1.3 lb) of pulled pork (a similar amount for beef)

A large dinner serving is 200 g (8 oz), or a typical dinner burrito requires 50 g, budget two burritos per person

There is a 20% to 40% loss by weight of fat and fluid depending on quality of pork and cooking method and temperature

Remember not to stuff your crock-pot above the inner rim, or it will overflow with the release of fat and fluids. Most crock-pots will not take more than 4 to 5 Kg (10 to 22 lb) of meat, and will take 20 to 24 hours to cook this amount on low

We produced pulled pork for burritos for 50 people last week, 5 Kg in one large crock-pot, 24 hours on low. The group eat a proper mixed diet, so meat serving size less than the typical North American slab. It was perfect :-)

Comment: 0.6kg is ~1.3lb.  And were the 50 people being served lunch or dinner, and were there other options that might affect amounts (eg, a vegetarian alternative)?

Answer (score 0):

Host a lot of parties, typically I plan on 1 pound per person as a general rule of thumb.