# I am buying fried chicken already made and making pulled pork for 100 people (80 adults and 20 children). How many pieces of chicken should I buy?

Tags: catering

How much fried chicken should I buy for 80 adults and 20 children? Pulled pork will be served as well as mac n cheese and green beans.

Comment: While some may have opinions about it, this is not an opinion-based question.  Looking at the "related" links one can see that there are several questions on the site that ask a similar question.  It's possible that it is a duplicate, but it is not an opinion based question.  Caterers ask and answer this question all of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer to the [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59215/how-much-meat-should-i-serve-per-person) Johanna linked, you should aim for about 8 oz or 225g of meat per person.  Without knowing how much pulled pork you intend to be serving, and which part of the chicken you're looking at, here is a breakdown of how much each piece of a broken down chicken weighs, so you can use that to figure out how much you want to serve.  [Source](https://www.chicken.org.au/chicken-cuts/#)

[image: Chicken weights]